# Swiper slider is not being correctly initialized and doesn't update React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I am building mobile time-picker using Swiper  plugin. I am having two weird issues, that I cannot fix on my own.

1. Swiper is unable to initialize slides according to current hours and minutes that I pass into it.
2. When I change hour in Swiper the state inside the component doesn't update, although the event fire correctly.

Here is my code (change only should work for hours):
https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-react-forked-d5oic?file=/src/index.tsx

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Wrap the initialSlide variable in parseInt(). Also, currentTime returns hours in 24 hour format yet you have only entered the 12 hour format

Comment: Ok, thanks, what about `updateTime` function, any ideas why it doesnt work ?

Comment: The moment object that you use (currentTime) is the same that you pass into changeCurrentTime. Hence the re-render does not occur.